# What does the CLEAN badge mean in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I noticed an indication 'CLEAN' on iTunes today. What does it mean?

Screenshot:
[image: clean]

Answer (score 2):

It is opposite to the Explicit version of a song, which may contain profanity or other unacceptable language. I do assume these don't have bad words in the text, etc. Unlike Explicit, which are more "clean" from author's point of view — they aren't "beeped" over phrases inappropriate before certain ages.

BTW there are several threads on Apple.com about people losing their Explicit versions after Music Match, just because songs are the same but Apple hasve a Clean version of it.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but nothing has been "beeped", even not the sentence "The bitch is hungry"(See [lyrics](http://www.lyricsondemand.com/onehitwonders/rockyoulikeahurricanelyrics.html) )

Answer (score 0):

Is there perhaps an EXPLICIT version? Then this would indicate it's the PG version.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Huh? I answered the question. I have no question of my own, but thank you for providing explicit (ha!) directions on how to ask one.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case that there is an "Explicit" version of a song and a "Clean" version. Makes me wonder what Kenny Loggins might be thinking that the Essential Kenny Loggins are all listed as "Clean."

Comment: Recently I've noticed 'clean' tags on things that had no tag before, and that don't have an alternate explicit version, such as podcasts. Maybe they just tag every song that meets their [Mastered for iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/) guidelines now, or something.